# Django register form POST data not validated by view in production?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

For some reason the POST data from my Django app's user sign up form doesn't get validated by the signup view. It works perfectly in development on my local machine, but not in production. I have also inspected the web content and the POST data gets created but the page just reloads an empty form. What could cause this?

**signup.html**

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% cache 86400 signup %}

        ...

        <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    {% endcache %}
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()

            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    context = {
        'title': 'Sign up',
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/signup.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The template caching was causing the form to render without the POST content, making it seem as if no validation is happening.

Comment: Have you considered using class based views? https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-signup-tutorial